# All GameObjects and Models are Transparent

Tags: unity

Whenever I create a new game object its completely transparent, with the Mesh Renderer selected.

[image]

This is really frustrating as I am new to Unity and Google offers no solutions.

Comment: Which version of Unity5?  I've been having problems with 5.3 myself (gray screen on startup) so it wouldn't surprise me if some other weird bugs abound.  I'd use the help menu to submit a bug report.

Comment: Yes! I had a thought it could be a bug with Unity 5.3, which I recently updated to. In that case, I'll submit a bug report as well. Still, do you think that there's any other reason why the cube in the picture isn't solid? Everything looks fine to you?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong, no. :\  Mind expanding the shader details?

Comment: Just a bunch of options that are inaccessible as they're blurred out.

Comment: I realize that, because its the default material. I was interested in figuring out if the default material was mistakenly marked as transparent or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your Default-Material is somehow messed up.  The little preview in the lower right looks wrong.

Try this:

In Unity, go to `Assets > Create > Material`.  Make sure the Shader is set to "Standard" and the Rendering Mode is set to "Opaque".  Now select your cube and apply the material in Element 0 of the `MeshRenderer`'s "Materials" list.

Also, I see you have an Editor folder. Check if you have any Editor scripts that are adjusting materials.  If this doesn't work, I'd re-install Unity because everything else looks correct.